# Add item to result set in asp.net mvc entity 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I looked at some of the other questions here and could not find my answer. Maybe I am not searching with the right keywords.

```
 public partial class CheckDirectReports_Result
{

    [Key]
    public Guid? id { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string EMPLID { get; set; }
    public short EMPL_RCD { get; set; }
    public bool hasSignedOff { get; set; }
}
```

So i have  a stored procedure that runs and returns the results just fine. I then want to loop thru the results and compare the ID to see if it exists. If it does i want to add a bool flag to the record to display in the view.

```
        var q = results.CheckDirectReports(EMPLID);


        foreach (var i in q.ToList())
        {
            var g = results.PERSON_SIGN_OFF.Where(p => p.EMPLID == i.EMPLID).FirstOrDefault();
            if(g != null)
            {
                i.hasSignedOff = true;
            }
            else
            {
                i.hasSignedOff = false;
            }
        }

        return View(q);
```

I initially had it return like this before i put in the loop and everything worked fine

```
return View(q.AsEnumerable());
```

The problem is it tells me the result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once.

Here is my view:

```
@model  IEnumerable<CodeOfConduct.Models.CheckDirectReports_Result>

<h2>Manager Sign Off</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Manager", FormMethod.Post))
{

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Employee ID</th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Select</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var c in Model) // Print the list
        {
            <tr>

                <td>@c.NAME</td>
                <td>@c.EMPLID </td>

                @{
            if (c.hasSignedOff == true)
            {
                <td class="bg-success">Employee Has completed Sign-off</td>
            }
            else
            {
                <td class="bg-danger">Employee has not completed Sign-off</td>
            }
}

                <td>

                    @Html.ActionLink("Select Employee", "SignOff", new { ids=c.EMPLID, name = c.NAME })  



                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Why is it telling me the result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once?

Comment: so what are you actually using now? `return View(q);`   or `return View(q.AsEnumerable());`??   `return View(q);` should work fine

Comment: `return View(q)` but the view is where the error is thrown. I will attempt the response below and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can return a List() to a View expecting an IEnumerable().

in your foreach, you enumerate the result q by doing q.ToList() just return `q` instead of `q.AsEnumerable()`

you can shorten your code using LINQ like this

```
    var q = results.CheckDirectReports(EMPLID).ToList();
    q.ForEach(a => {
        a.hasSignedOff = results.PERSON_SIGN_OFF.Any(p => p.EMPLID == a.EMPLID)
    });
    return View(q);
```

if there are few records in the `results.PERSON_SIGN_OFF` i would select them all ToList() then check if the EMPLID exists to prevent multiple hits to the db.

```
    var q = results.CheckDirectReports(EMPLID).ToList();
    var signOffs = results.PERSON_SIGN_OFF.ToList();
    q.ForEach(a => {
        a.hasSignedOff = signOffs.Any(p => p.EMPLID == a.EMPLID)
    });
    return View(q);
```

there might be an even better way to do this but we'd need to know more about your data structure

Comment: You are amazing! i changed the  query to the second example you gave and it works like a charm!